# AngularJS textarea counter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created a contact form with a textarea in it, and I want to display the minimum character count needed to make the form valid:

```
<div class="field form-group">
        <label for="message" class="form-label">Your Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" ng-model="contactData.sender_message"  class="form-control" rows="6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactForm.message.$touched && contactForm.message.$invalid }" ng-minlength="10" ng-trim="false" placeholder="Questions? Comments? Concerns?" required></textarea>
        <p ng-show="contactForm.message.$error.minlength">{{10 - contactData.sender_message.length}}</p>
</div>
```

The issue with this is that it only displays "10" and it doesn't update, it just goes away after 10 characters are typed in. My guess is that something is wrong with my length, but I'm not sure.

Sidenote: Is there also anyway I can have the character count show as soon as the textarea is clicked inside, instead of just when the user starts typing in it?

Comment: Did you initialize the variable in the controller? it may begin as null or undefined. (Inside the controller: `$scope.contactData.sender_message = ""`)

Comment: Also, try to change `contactForm.message.$error.minlength` to `!contactForm.message.$valid`

Comment: Issue is `model` data is not set unless `minlength` is satisfied. Try removing `ng-minlength="10"` and check.

Comment: try `{{10 - contactForm.message.$viewValue.length}}`

Comment: @entre that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using
`{{10 - contactForm.message.$viewValue.length}}`

Answer (score 2):

> Information

You were really close to what you needed, but I have made a couple changes.

- Use `$viewValue.length` *instead of* `contactData.sender_message.length`<sup>[1]</sup>
- Use `ng-click="contactForm.message.$touched = true"` to set the `$touched` value to true when the user clicks on the textarea.*
- Use the `has-error` class on the same div as the div with the `form-group` class.

> Example

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.contactData = {
    sender_message: ""
  };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <form name="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="field form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactForm.message.$touched && contactForm.message.$invalid }">
      <label for="message" class="form-label">Your Message:</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" ng-model="contactData.sender_message" class="form-control" rows="6" ng-minlength="10" ng-trim="false" placeholder="Questions? Comments? Concerns?"
      ng-click="contactForm.message.$touched = true" required></textarea>
      <p ng-show="contactForm.message.$touched">Min Length {{(10 - contactForm.message.$viewValue.length) > 0 ? (10 - contactForm.message.$viewValue.length) : "Met" }}</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

*Note: This may go against common practices in AngularJS; it may not be recommended. You should consider making a custom validator. See [AngularJS form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) for more details.

<sup>[1]</sup> Credit to @entre for idea of using `$viewValue`